# How do I populate cell based on value from two separate cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can anyone help me write the below formula the correct way?

```
=IF(C13="North Dakota","$2,500",IF(C13="Montana","$2,500",IF(C15="Yes","$5,000","")))
```

What I wish to achieve is:  If value selected in C13 equals North Dakota OR Montana AND value selected in C15 equals Yes, then I want value in C17 to be $5,000 BUT if value in C13 equals North Dakota or Montana and value selected in C15 equals No, then I want value in C17 to be $2,500.

How do I such a formula?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If either of the conditions for C13 and C15 is not met, what do you want the formula to return? Nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You are headed in the right direction. Combining `AND` and `OR` functions into your nested `IF` statement will help.

Use two different `IF` statements to ask Excel if `C13` contains "Montana" **`OR`** "North Dakota" **`AND`** whether `C15` contains "Yes" or "No", then respond according to the results.

```
=IF(AND(OR(C13="North Dakota",C13="Montana"),C15="Yes"),"$5,000",
IF(AND(OR(C13="North Dakota",C13="Montana"),C15="No"),"$2,500", ""))
```

In this example, the first `IF` will check for either "North Dakota" or "Montana" in `C13` and "Yes" in `C15`. If that is TRUE, it will return "$5,000".

The second `IF` will check for either "North Dakota" or "Montana" in `C13` and "No" in `C15`. If that is TRUE, it will return "$2,500".

If both statements are FALSE, nothing is returned. This formula will return FALSE if `C13` is anything other than those to states or if `C15` contains anything other than "Yes" or "No".

*(Note: the example is on two lines to make it easy to see the differences. In Excel, this will be on the same line.)*